# How to Get Json Array in C# ?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a Json String Like this ,,  and i wana load it in C# Array .. When i try to do this i am getting Exception

My String :

```
 {
"customerInformation":
[
  {
     "customerId":"123",
     "CustomerName":"",
     "Age":39,
     "Gender":"Male",
     "StudyInfo":[
        {
           "Modality":"XRAY",
           "StudyName":"Test Name",
           "ModalityId":"1",
           "StudyID":"10923",
           "visitid":41549113,
           "billingId":"456",
           "RegDate":"mm/dd/yyyy",
           "uploaded":"1",
           "groupid":"1"

        },
        {
           "Modality":"XRAY",
           "StudyName":"CT Test Name",
           "ModalityId":"1",
           "StudyID":"10924",
           "visitid":41549113,
           "billingId":"459",
           "RegDate":"mm/dd/yyyy",
           "uploaded":"1",
           "groupid":"1"

        }
     ]
  },

  {
     "customerId":"928",
     "CustomerName":"",
     "Age":49,
     "Gender":"FeMale",
     "StudyInfo":[
        {
           "Modality":"XRAY",
           "StudyName":"Test Name",
           "ModalityId":"1",
           "StudyID":"10923",
           "visitid":41549113,
           "billingId":"456",
           "RegDate":"mm/dd/yyyy",
           "uploaded":"1",
           "groupid":"1"
        },
        {
           "Modality":"XRAY",
           "StudyName":"CT Test Name",
           "ModalityId":"1",
           "StudyID":"10924",
           "visitid":41549113,
           "billingId":"459",
           "RegDate":"mm/dd/yyyy",
           "uploaded":"1",
           "groupid":"1"
        }
     ]
  }

]

 }
```

My Code :

```
public class Attributes
{


    public string[] customerId { get; set; }
    public string[] CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string[] Age { get; set; }
    public string[] Gender { get; set; }
    public string[] StudyInfo { get; set; }
    public string[] Modality { get; set; }
    public string[] StudyName { get; set; }
    public string[] ModalityId { get; set; }
    public string[] StudyID { get; set; }
    public string[] visitid { get; set; }
    public string[] billingId { get; set; }
    public string[] RegDate { get; set; }
    public string[] uploaded { get; set; }
}

public class DataJsonAttributeContainer
{
    public List<Attributes> attributes { get; set; }
}

 public static T DeserializeFromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        T deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
       return deserializedProduct;
    }

   public void testing()
    {
  var container = DeserializeFromJson<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(JsonString);

    }
```

"This returns Null"

And I have tried this also

```
            JArray jArray = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonStr);
            dynamic dynObj1 = jArray.OrderByDescending(x => x["customerId"]);
```

Both Cases got Failed... How to load this .. I am using Newtonsoft.Json Dll

Comment: Try a smaller sample first and work your way up. Some hints a long the way is that the object you are converting to should have the same structure as the json, which it doesn't in your sample code.

Comment: In your json the array is called 'customerInformation' but in your container class it's called 'attributes'. Try using the same name in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user2552410!

Maybe you need to change your class structure. You can work with List<>

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ConsoleApplication2.TestService;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string customerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public StudyInfoType[] StudyInfo { get; set; }
        public string visited { get; set; }
        public string billingId { get; set; }
        public string RegDate { get; set; }
        public string uploaded { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudyInfoType
    {
           string Modality {get; set;}
           string StudyName {get; set;}
           string ModalityId {get; set;}
           string StudyID {get; set;}
           string visitid {get; set;}
           string billingId {get; set;}
           string RegDate {get; set;}
           string uploaded {get; set;}
           string groupid { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var temp = CustomerInfo(@"[{ 'customerId':'123', 'CustomerName':'', 'Age':39,'Gender':'Male','StudyInfo':[{'Modality':'XRAY','StudyName':'Test Name','ModalityId':'1','StudyID':'10923','visitid':41549113,'billingId':'456','RegDate':'mm/dd/yyyy','uploaded':'1','groupid':'1'},{'Modality':'XRAY','StudyName':'CT Test Name','ModalityId':'1','StudyID':'10924','visitid':41549113,'billingId':'459','RegDate':'mm/dd/yyyy','uploaded':'1','groupid':'1'}]},{'customerId':'928','CustomerName':'','Age':49,'Gender':'FeMale','StudyInfo':[{'Modality':'XRAY','StudyName':'Test Name','ModalityId':'1','StudyID':'10923','visitid':41549113,'billingId':'456','RegDate':'mm/dd/yyyy','uploaded':'1','groupid':'1'},{ 'Modality':'XRAY','StudyName':'CT Test Name','ModalityId':'1','StudyID':'10924','visitid':41549113,'billingId':'459','RegDate':'mm/dd/yyyy','uploaded':'1','groupid':'1' } ] } ]");
        }

        public static List<Customer> CustomerInfo(string json)
        {
            var n = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
            });
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But string should start with "customerInformation": you directly added Customer id

Comment: Yes, it's right. To my mind, it will be more better to create two more tables. One for "CustomerInformstion" and one for "Visit Detailes". The table "CustomerInformation" will contain List<Visit Detailes"

Answer (score 9):

The way you generated you objects is wrong, It should be something like:

```
public class StudyInfo
{
    public string Modality { get; set; }
    public string StudyName { get; set; }
    public string ModalityId { get; set; }
    public string StudyID { get; set; }
    public int visitid { get; set; }
    public string billingId { get; set; }
    public string RegDate { get; set; }
    public string uploaded { get; set; }
    public string groupid { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerInformation
{
    public string customerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public List<StudyInfo> StudyInfo { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<CustomerInformation> customerInformation { get; set; }
}
```

By the way, you can try [json2charp](http://json2csharp.com/), for stuff like this, it's pretty awesome.